# How do I determine the total size of a directory (folder) from the command line?

Tags: filesystem, command-line

Is there a simple command to display the total aggregate size (disk usage) of all files in a directory (folder)?

I have tried these, and they don't do what I want:

- `ls -l`, which only displays the size of the individual files in a directory, nor
- `df -h`, which only displays the free and used space on my disks.

Comment: Friendly reminder that it may make nearly zero sense on CoW filesystem like BTRFS.

Answer (score 1908, accepted):

The command `du` "summarizes disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories," e.g.,

```
du -hs /path/to/directory
```

- `-h` is to get the numbers "human readable", e.g. get `140M` instead of `143260` (size in KBytes)
- `-s` is for summary (otherwise you'll get not only the size of the folder but also for everything *in* the folder separately)

---

As you're using `-h` you can sort the human readable values using

```
du -h | sort -h
```

The `-h` flag on `sort` will consider "Human Readable" size values.

---

If want to avoid recursively listing all files and directories, you can supply the `--max-depth` parameter to limit how many items are displayed. Most commonly, `--max-depth=1`

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /path/to/directory
```

Comment: I use `du -sh` or DOOSH as a way to remember it (NOTE: the command is the same, just the organization of commandline flags for memory purposes)

Comment: There is a useful option to du called the --apparent-size. It can be used to find the actual size of a file or directory (as opposed to its footprint on the disk) eg, a text file with just 4 characters will occupy about 6 bytes, but will still show up as taking up ~4K in a regular du -sh output. However, if you pass the --apparent-size option, the output will be 6. man du says:

 --apparent-size print  apparent  sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in  (‘sparse’) files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks

Comment: This works for OS X too! Thanks, I was really looking for a way to clear up files, both on my local machine, and my server, but automated methods seemed not to work. So, I ran `du -hs *` and went into the largest directory and found out which files were so large... This is such a good method, and the best part is you don't have to install anything! Definitely deserved my upvote

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal I think there are two reasons: rounding (`du` has somewhat peculiar rounding, showing no decimals if the value has more than one digit in the chosen unit), and the classical [1024 vs. 1000 prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Deviation_between_powers_of_1024_and_powers_of_1000) issue. `du` has an option `-B` (or `--block-size`) to change the units in which it displays values, or you could use `-b` instead of `-h` to get the "raw" value in bytes.

Comment: Sounds like asking a question 'Du hast'

Answer (score 238):

Recently I found a great, ncurses based interactive tool, that quickly gives you an overview about directory sizes. Searched for that kind of tool for years.

- quickly drilldown through file hierarchy
- you can delete e.g. huge temporary files from inside the tool
- extremely fast

Think of it as [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) for the command line:

```
apt-get install ncdu
```

Edit:
You can restrict the search to files in the same filesystem, use `-x`:

```
ncdu -x /
```

this will ignore other mounted filesystems outside where the root filesystem is hosted.

A slightly optimization is using the '-q' option to increase the time between screen updates. The options can be combined:

```
ncdu -xq /var
```

As always, reading `man ncdu` is recommended.

Comment: `ncdu` is awesome! After installing it, just do this `ncdu /`. You will very quickly find the biggest files on the system. Also press `h` while inside ncdu's console interface. It has very useful shortcuts

Comment: cool tool. use the man page to find all the cool shortcuts like `a` which shows the apparent size of all the files. That's the biggest problem I have with `du` it takes too much typing to see the apparent size, which is usually what I really want to know.

Comment: To see information about the shortcuts just press `?` within _ncdu_ (not `h`).

Answer (score 100):

This finds the size recursively and puts it next to each folder name, along with total size at the bottom, all in the human format

```
du -hsc *
```

Comment: Use  `du -hsc * | sort -hr` if you want to get a sorted list of folders

Answer (score 25):

Below is what I am using to print total, folder, and file size:

```
$ du -sch /home/vivek/* | sort -rh
```

#### Details

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
   -c, --total
          produce a grand total
   -h, --human-readable
          print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
   -s, --summarize
          display only a total for each argument
 -------------------------------------------------------------
   -h, --human-numeric-sort
          compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
   -r, --reverse
          reverse the result of comparisons
```

#### Output

```
 70M    total
 69M    /home/vivek/Downloads/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.2/lib
992K    /home/vivek/Downloads/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.2/results
292K    /home/vivek/Downloads/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.2/target
 52K    /home/vivek/Downloads/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.2/user-files
```

Answer (score 22):

Enjoy!

```
du foldername
```

More information on that command [here](http://www.linfo.org/du.html)

Comment: Yep. I prefer adding ```-h``` to make "Human readable" folder size. ```du -h foldername```

Answer (score 17):

`tree` is another useful command for this job:

Just install it via `sudo apt-get install tree` and type the following:

```
tree --du -h /path/to/directory
...
...

33.7M used in 0 directories, 25 files
```

From [man tree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tree.1.html):

```
-h    Print  the size of each file but in a more human readable way, e.g. appending a size letter for kilo‐
      bytes (K), megabytes (M), gigabytes (G), terabytes (T), petabytes (P) and exabytes (E).

--du  For each directory report its size as the accumulation of sizes of all its files and  sub-directories
      (and their files, and so on). The total amount of used space is also given in the final report (like
      the 'du -c' command.)
```

Answer (score 8):

To see the sizes of all files and directories, use

```
du -had1 dir/
```

(maybe like "do you had 1")

- `du`: device/disk usage
- `-h`: human readable sizes
- `-a`: show files, not just directories
- `-d1`: show totals only at depth 1, i.e. the current directory's contents

For the current directory, the directory argument can be left off.

`du -sh dir/*` has the same effect but doesn't show hidden files and directories due to shell globbing.

Answer (score 7):

The answers have made it obvious that `du` is the tool to find the total size of a directory. However, there are a couple of factors to consider:

- Occasionally, `du` output can be misleading because it reports the space allocated by the filesystem, which may be different from the sum of the sizes of the individual files. Typically the filesystem will allocate 4096 bytes for a file even if you stored just one character in it!
- Output differences due to power of 2 and power of 10 units. The `-h` switch to `du` divides the number of bytes by 2^10 (1024), 2^20 (1048576) etc to give a human readable output. Many people might be more habituated to seeing powers of 10 (e.g. 1K = 1000, 1M = 1000000) and be surprised by the result.

To find the total sum of sizes of all files in a directory, in bytes, do:

```
find <dir> -ls | awk '{sum += $7} END {print sum}'
```

Example:

```
$ du -s -B 1
255729664

$ find .  -ls | awk '{sum += $7} END {print sum}'
249008169
```

Comment: The find-ls-awk will return a wrong value for large folders [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857866/printing-long-integers-in-awk). For newer awk you can add `--bignum` or `-M` ;  if that is not an option use `find .  -ls  | tr -s ' '|cut -d' ' -f 7| paste -sd+ |bc` [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277631/awk-sum-of-large-integers).

Comment: If powers of 2 being used is a problem, there's the `--si` option: "like -h, but use powers of 1000 not 1024"

Comment: found here the explanation of why an rcloned directory had significantly different total sizes, between the original usb disk (512K blocks/sectors/whatever) and the destination directory on an internal disk (4k). Used tree to get number of sub-directories and files and validated they were the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the tool Dust:

```
PS C:\git> dust
   0B       ┌── templates           │                                      █ │   0%
   0B     ┌─┴ git-core              │                                      █ │   0%
   0B   ┌─┴ share                   │                                      █ │   0%
  76B   ├── readme.md               │                                      █ │   0%
 156K   │   ┌── less.exe            │▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█ │   2%
 2.7M   │   ├── git-remote-https.exe│▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████ │  42%
 3.6M   │   ├── git.exe             │▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██████████████████████ │  56%
 6.5M   │ ┌─┴ git-core              │███████████████████████████████████████ │ 100%
 6.5M   ├─┴ libexec                 │███████████████████████████████████████ │ 100%
 6.5M ┌─┴ .                         │███████████████████████████████████████ │ 100%
```

My example is from Windows, but Linux and Apple are also supported:

https://github.com/bootandy/dust

Comment: I like how it uses a single screen to show biggest subdirs.

Comment: cool use of a CLI bar chart.

Answer (score 3):

If your desired directory has many sub-directories then, use the following:

```
$ cd ~/your/target/directory
$ du -csh
```

> -c, --total           produce a grand total
>   -s, --summarize       display only a total for each argument
>   -h, --human-readable  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

which would then produce a overall total of the memory usage by all files/folders in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm conditioned to the `ll` command which is aliased to `ls -alF`. It is just missing a file count and size of files at the bottom. I played with `du` and `tree` but could not get the totals I needed. So I created `lll` to do that for me.

In your `~/.bashrc` place the following:

```bsh
lll () {
    ls -alF "$@"
    arr=($(ls -alF "$@" | awk '{TOTAL+=$5} END {print NR, TOTAL}'))
    printf " \33[1;31m ${arr[0]}\33[m line(s).  "
    printf "Total size: \33[1;31m ${arr[1]}\33[m\n"
#    printf "Total size: \33[1;31m $(BytesToHuman <<< ${arr[1]})\33[m\n"
}
```

Save the file and resource it using `. ~/.bashrc` (or you can restart your terminal).

---

### Sample output

The nice thing about `ll` output is it's colors. This is maintained with `lll` but lost when using `find` or `du`:

[image: lll sample output.png]

---

### TL;DR

A bonus function you can add to `~/.bashrc` is called `BytesToHuman()`. This does what most console users would expect converting large numbers to MiB, GiB, etc:

```bsh
function BytesToHuman() {

    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/a-standard-tool-to-convert-a-byte-count-into-human-kib-mib-etc-like-du-ls1/259254#259254

    read StdIn

    b=${StdIn:-0}; d=''; s=0; S=(Bytes {K,M,G,T,E,P,Y,Z}iB)
    while ((b > 1024)); do
        d="$(printf ".%02d" $((b % 1024 * 100 / 1024)))"
        b=$((b / 1024))
        let s++
    done
    echo "$b$d ${S[$s]}"

} # BytesToHuman ()
```

Next flip the comment between two lines in `lll ()` function to look like this:

```bsh
#    printf "Total size: \33[1;31m ${arr[1]}\33[m\n"
    printf "Total size: \33[1;31m $(BytesToHuman <<< ${arr[1]})\33[m\n"
```

Now your output looks like this:

[image: lll sample output 2.png]

As always don't forget to re-source with `. ~/.bashrc` whenever making changes. (Or restart the terminal of course)

PS - Two weeks in self-quarantine finally gave me time to work on this five year old goal.

Answer (score 2):

`du /foldername` is the standard command to know the size of a folder. It is  best practice to find the options by reading the man page:

```
man du
```

You should read the man page (available [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/du)) before you use the command.

Answer (score 2):

For only the directory size in a readable format, use the below:

```
du -hs directoryname
```

This probably isn't in the correct section, but from the command line, you could try:

```
ls -sh filename
```

The `-s` is size, and the `-h` is human readable.

Use `-l` to show on `ls` list, like below:

```
ls -shl
```

Comment: `-s` will not show directory sizes

Comment: @qwr you are not correct. i just tested : https://prnt.sc/103jxmq

Comment: that's not a directory!

Comment: @qwr use `du -hs` for directory : example https://prnt.sc/103oxza

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`7z`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z) (`sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`) to determine the total apparent size of a directory from the command line. Example:

```
7z -mx=0 a temp16584.zip /path/to/directory
```

It will show the total size of a directory (as well as the number of files):

```
(base) user@server:~$ 7z -mx=0 a temp16584.zip /path/to/directory

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8275CL CPU @ 3.00GHz (50657),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
7829 folders, 684576 files, 6914280912739 bytes (6440 GiB)                     

Creating archive: temp16584.zip

Items to compress: 692405
```

To get both the actual and apparent total size of a directory, one may use [`ncdu`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncdu) (`sudo apt-get install ncdu`):

[image]

Keyboard shortcut in `ncdu` to toggle between showing disk usage and showing apparent size: `a`. Same folders as above but now showing the apparent sizes for each folder:

[image]