# How to determine where biggest files/directories on my system are stored?

Tags: filesystem, disk, memory, command-line

I was wondering how do you know where the largest files in my system are stored.

For example---

Disk Space Used: 1GB
Java: 500MB
Java Percentage: 50% maybe represented in a pie chart. Maybe?

I know this maybe a feature overkill. I sometimes forget having stored things and wonder why my disk is so full.

So basically a command that will allow me to run on the file system and provide me with information on disk space used.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The Disk Usage Analyzer is available under Ubuntu > Accessories > Disk Usage Analyzer. It provides you with a snazzy pie graph showing what files and folders take up the most space:

[image]

The documentation on it is a little sparse, but you can find more information on [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab), and the [project page](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/).

If you're interested in using the command line, there's `du` which is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1224).

Comment: Mmm. Delicious pie...

Comment: Disk Usage Analyzer does not show individual files, only directories. It is very difficult to analyze a directory without this information, so it is actually of little use.

Comment: Using this to find problem directories, it's fairly easy to ls -l that directory to look for large files.

Comment: `sudo apt install baobab` for other *ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 33):

Unless it changed recently, `baobab` only shows directories; check out [kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) for an alternative that actually shows files, coloured by type.

A commandline alternative is

```
du -a | sort -nr | head
```

Answer (score 27):

The solution that @UncleZeiv proposed is not working when there is really no more space left, since sort is using the `/tmp` folder when there are multiple lines to sort.

```
du -a | sort -nr | head
sort: write failed: /tmp/sortuCYq8E: No space left on device
```

An alternative is a combination of the answer from @UncleZeiv and @Yoav Weiss, plus adding another path for the temporary location:

```
sudo du -a | sort -nr -T /media/usb-key
```

Finally, my preferred solution will be a human-readable one that doesn't depend on temp folder and list root directory (`/`):

```
sudo du -ah --max-depth=1  / | sort -hr
```

Comment: This should be the best answer

Answer (score 10):

A useful command to that helps in cases you need to determine that for specific directories from the command line:

```
du --max-depth=1 -x -h
```

It gives you a list of the first depth directories and their sizes

`-x` limits the analysis to one file system

`-h` shows human readable k/M/Gbytes (this prevents you from sorting the output though)

Answer (score 3):

The other excellent pie-graph disk usage tool is Filelight. It's a KDE app, and it's available in the repositories.

Comment: It depends on kde-runtime and a few other KDE utilities, so it's likely not pure Qt. Thus it will probably be more suitable for Kubuntu users.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the Disk Usage Analyser (Applications -> Accessories -> Disk Usage Analyser):

(The command is `baobab`).

Click Analyser -> Scan Filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Another tool for this is [jDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) (a Java app)