# Nautilus statusbar visibilty - Quickly check free space

Tags: nautilus, disk-usage, usability

In prior versions, I would open Nautilus and check the statusbar, which would tell me how much free space there is. Now, the statusbar isn't shown by default. I know you can enable it from the View menu, but 99% of users won't do that (and I'd rather not do that, if possible). So, is there some new recommended way to keep tabs on hard drive usage? Or is there maybe some other method that I should have been using in the past but never noticed?

Comment: You have this link for command line usage: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21068/how-to-get-disk-usage-from-command-line and you have here a couple of gui tools for that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17467/what-is-taking-up-so-much-space-on-my-disk-beside-the-filesystem (Disk Analyzer, Disk Utility). Type "Disk" in the dash to see them. If they answer your question feel free to close the question since it would be a possible duplicate of them.

Comment: So you're saying people need to either drop to the command line or install some dedicated tools for this? Seems like a usability issue, no?

Comment: If the options I gave you in the comment fulfill your need then there is no need to have the duplicate question. If they do not fulfill it then of course keep the question. That is up to you.

Comment: @Jeremy Disk Usage Analyzer and System Monitor are both installed by default, no need to install them. But more importantly, as you pointed out, you can simply enable the status bar from the view menu to see disk space. I'm not sure what simple method you're looking for here. This is sounding more like a rant than a question.

Comment: I suppose it's kind of a rant, but also a question about usability.

Comment: you cannot view the status bar from the view menu in the latest builds for Gnome 3.5.4 . i think its disabled forever.

Comment: I cannot understand these Gnome's decisions... The statusbar for looking free space was largely used by users, why remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to find out how much hard disk space is available.

- [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2045/how-to-determine-where-biggest-files-directories-on-my-system-are-stored)
- [Terminal commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5444/how-to-find-out-how-much-disk-space-is-remaining)
- System Monitor
- Conky

or a number of other utilities.

But I don't think any of them are going to be as simple as checking the status bar in a Nautilus window.

Comment: Disk Usage Analyzer just spins and spins for me.

Answer (score 5):

Good ol' right-click an empty area in Nautilus, then select Properties.

Answer (score 4):

Click on your Dash Home and type Disk Usage Analyzer. On the Disk Usage Analyzer and click  Scan Home to scan your hard disk for usage.You will see how your disk is been used by your system.

Comment: He is interested in seeing how much free disk space there is, not how much space each directory is using.

Comment: Yes! Free disk space, usage among others are displayed there.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`) you can enable the default behavior of the status bar.

Type this on your terminal to enable the status bar by default

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-status-bar true
```

Type this on your terminal to disable the status bar by default

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-status-bar false
```

Comment: I get `No such key 'start-with-status-bar'` with those gsettings commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this extension](https://github.com/benintech/Nautilus-Status-Bar-Replacement)

Tested on Gnome 3.38

[image]