# What programs are used to check free/used memory, disk space, and to manage tasks like the Task Manager in Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where’s the “task manager”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2123/wheres-the-task-manager)
>   [How to find out how much disk space is remaining?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5444/how-to-find-out-how-much-disk-space-is-remaining)

How do I see how much memory I'm using?
How do I see how much disk space is free?
Is there a program like task manager in windows?

Comment: Or maybe this one: http://askubuntu.com/q/2123/44179

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "System Monitor" is the Windows equivalent of the "Task Manager", you can use it to view how much hard drive space you have as well as how much RAM you are using.

[image]

[image]

You can also use `top` to find information on running process'.

Answer (score 1):

```
df -lh
```

It checks your disk free in a long human readable format.

There is also a bulit-in software to see your RAM useage,unfortunately whose name escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actualy call it memory on a HDD, just disk space. Go into the dash home and search for system monitor. Go to the right-most tab (filesystem) it will show you how much space is left for each partition.
System monitor will give you all the info about your system.

Comment: While hard disks [are memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_memory#Non-volatile_memory), you're right that *memory* should probably not be used to refer to *disk space*, as it's confusing.