# Software Updater forces updates

Tags: updates

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy)

One of the most Anoying things is Software Updater.  The UPDATES tab first option "Subscribe to" lets me subscribe to ALL updates, Security and Recommended updates, or Security Updates only.  No option for NONE which is what I really want. It's extremely offensive that I'm not in control of the software on my computer. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn off automatic updates COMPLETELY and FOR REAL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322292/how-do-i-turn-off-automatic-updates-completely-and-for-real)

Comment: I don't want the updates to be forced because over the years lots of companies claim it's just to fix things and somehow they end up changing the look and feel or applying what THEY think is more secure but I don't agree.  in Short I no longer trust other conpanies/groups and I want 100% control over MY system.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to nothing makes no sense.
You can set automatically check for updates to "NEVER".
Nothing is installed automatically if you do not set it to be installed automatically (except snaps)