# VirtualBox "sudo apt install openssh-server" ERROR after doing "sudo killall apt apt-get" it returns "apt: no process found apt-get: no process found"

Tags: apt, ssh, virtualbox, dpkg

I'm a bit new here to AskUbuntu (this is my first post), but there is an extremely annoying problem when I try:

```
user@machine:/etc$ sudo apt install openssh-server 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`
```

This is annoying because I was trying to setup a Minecraft server and operate it via `ssh` but this is not letting me. I tryed `sudo killall apt apt-get` but its not letting me and returning:

```
user@machine:/etc$ sudo killall apt apt-get
apt: no process found 
apt-get: no process found
```

Do you reckon that I should update? VB (VirtualBox) always is saying
[update to newer version](https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/73d902cb-2db7-4b1f-a5ce-76aea0f3468b/downloads/j.png?ver=1621636886158).
This is not a copy of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari).
I'm starting to think about if should log on as root, or if I should remove the machine or not.

It's so annoying. ):( I can't stand it!

> Hi guys, I fixed it by installing it by
> `sudo su`
> then
> `sudo apt install openssh-server`

Comment: It feels disappointing to realize I fixed it straight after I posted it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop apt from doing anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006189/how-to-stop-apt-from-doing-anything)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109982/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-11-resource-temporari)