# How can I find out when systemd schedules apt to auto-upgrade my packages?

Tags: 18.04, apt, cron, systemd

The other day [I found out that my Docker container had been killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780402/how-can-i-find-out-why-a-docker-container-is-no-longer-running?noredirect=1#comment121554346_68780402) as the docker daemon had been automatically upgraded on an AWS box I was running.

`journald` showed these messages in the relevant time slot:

```
Aug 06 05:56:01 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Aug 06 05:56:11 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Aug 06 06:06:39 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 06 06:06:48 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug 06 06:06:48 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Aug 06 06:06:48 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug 06 06:06:49 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug 06 06:06:49 ip-192-168-3-117 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
```

How can I know when this is scheduled to run? I looked through the various cron jobs in `/etc` and I thought `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` was involved, since it contained this at the end:

```
# delay the job execution by a random amount of time
random_sleep

# ensure we don't do this on battery
check_power || exit 0

# run daily job
exec /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
```

but it turns out it never gets that far, as it actually just uses `systemd`. I overlooked this at the start of `cron.daily/apt-compat`:

```
# Systemd systems use a systemd timer unit which is preferable to
# run. We want to randomize the apt update and unattended-upgrade
# runs as much as possible to avoid hitting the mirrors all at the
# same time. The systemd time is better at this than the fixed
# cron.daily time
if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

So somehow systemd schedules this to run instead.

That file, `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`, basically seems like the script responsible, although I cannot find any of the strings above, like "Starting .* activities".

So systemd is scheduling this, but where is this stored? Where does is it told to run `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`?

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006189/how-to-stop-apt-from-doing-anything, which has about nothing in common with this question. It asks how to stop Apt from doing anything, while I want to know where the time settings are stored for systemd. 

I do not mind a question being closed, but this was the wrong duplicate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a systemd timer. You can check the status of systemd timers using:

```
systemctl list-timers
```

It should list an `apt-daily.timer`. You can inspect its specification using:

```
systemctl show apt-daily.timer
```

The file is located in [`/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=apt-daily.timer). (Do not edit that file directly if you want to modify the timer. See [How do I override or configure systemd services?](https://askubuntu.com/q/659267/158442))