# The computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 a month ago alongside Windows 10, so I don't know much about Ubuntu. I got the following error:

```
The computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining.
```

The error says to remove unused programs or by moving files to external disk, but how do I do that?

Here is the output of `df` :

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3897864         0   3897864   0% /dev
tmpfs             785524     78192    707332  10% /run
/dev/sda6      190492356 181956696         0 100% /
tmpfs            3927612       364   3927248   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3927612         0   3927612   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             785524        32    785492   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3      184319996 121988304  62331692  67% /media/fauad/649EEF6E9EEF3768
/dev/sda2      101887996  78061748  23826248  77% /media/fauad/A8A2E811A2E7E234
```

Here is the output of `df -i` :

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             974466    653   973813    1% /dev
tmpfs            981903    808   981095    1% /run
/dev/sda6      12107776 520795 11586981    5% /
tmpfs            981903     11   981892    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            981903      5   981898    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            981903     17   981886    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            981903     23   981880    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3      62397228   5078 62392150    1% /media/fauad/649EEF6E9EEF3768
/dev/sda2      24416072 521305 23894767    3% /media/fauad/A8A2E811A2E7E234
```

Comment: Please open a terminal, run the commands `df` and `df -i`, and copy-and-paste the complete output of both commands into your question.

Comment: I have added the outputs of  commands df and df -i

Comment: Your Ubuntu partition seems to be full. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/2045/how-to-determine-where-biggest-files-directories-on-my-system-are-stored to determine what it's full of, so you can make informed choices of what to delete.

Comment: My var folder seems to be full

Comment: Keep going. Which subfolder insider /var? Which subfolder inside that?

Comment: But i cannot delete files from it as i dont have nautilus

Comment: The log folder contains most data

Comment: Find our what problem is filling your log...and fix it. Normal daily log rotation will get rid of the big logfiles.

Comment: How can i delete the syslog files ? The move to trash option is greyed out .

Comment: Have you read the log(s) to determine what the real problem is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do) From OP's comment above it seems to be an issue of huge log file(s).

Comment: I would run `sudo apt autoremove` to get at least a bit free space. then install ncdu via `sudo apt install ncdu` and run `ncdu /`. ncdu is a small interactive disk-usage helper. It might help understanding which folders are big ... and therefor be a good starting point