# Check if a package is required or whether it can be safely deleted

Tags: package-management, dpkg, cleanup

I can get the list of packages using command: 
`dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package;-50}\t${Installed-Size}\n' | sort -k 2 -n | grep -v deinstall | awk '{printf "%.3f MB \t %s\n", $2/(1024), $1}'`

and now I would like to know  whether the particular package is critical for the system or not. If the package is no longer required then I will delete them. I want free up root space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting packages is rarely an effective way to free up space in the root filesystem. Packages are small and numerous.

- Look for large (runaway) logfiles in /var/log. Those can free up a lot of space quickly! Remember that a runaway log is merely a *symptom* of a problem that still needs to be investigated and fixed.
- Look for large personal files in your /home. A movie or two takes up a lot of storage. Occasionally, folks who have a separate /home discover that it failed to mount and all their data is in the root filesystem instead.
- Run `baobab` (also known as Disk Usage Analyzer) to search for large files on your root filesystem. It's included with every stock install of Ubuntu Desktop -- use your Desktop Search to find it. If you are on a Server instead of a desktop, [here are some good techniques to find big files using `du`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2045/how-to-determine-where-biggest-files-directories-on-my-system-are-stored)

Here's one easy, safe way to determine is a package is system-critical:

`apt remove --simulate <package_name>`

- The `--simulate` option means that the removal WON'T actually take place. An additional protection is omitting `sudo`.

Read the output: If only the package is removed (and perhaps a few dependencies), then it is likely safe to remove.

However, if the list of proposed removals includes one of these red flags, then DON'T do it for real:

1. The list is lengthy
2. The list includes applications that you use
3. The list includes one of the desktop meta-packages (`ubuntu-desktop`, `kubuntu-desktop`, etc.)
4. The list includes the `apt`, `dpkg`, `python3`, or `python3-minimal` packages (removing those would destroy your package manager)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command removes packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed.

Also try

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This command removes .deb files for packages that are no longer installed on your system. Depending on your installation habits, removing these files from /var/cache/apt/archives may regain a significant amount of diskspace.

To get information on a package use

```
apt-cache show <package_name>
```

This command shows the description of package <package_name> and other relevant information including version, size, dependencies and conflicts.

For further info read this [HowTo on AptGet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

If you want to use dpkg try

```
dpkg -I package.deb
```

for information of a specific package