# How to migrate the whole system to a new machine?

Tags: backup, clipboard, migration

I use `ubuntu` to deal with daily job. Now I buy a new laptop, and I want to migrate my whole system(programs, packages, data, settings, etc) to the new machine.

I know I can copy my home folder to new machine and I will get (almost) all data and settings. But is there a safe way to copy the whole system? Or it's a bad idea?

Comment: Is anything stopping you from swapping the old drive to the new system, or the image of it to a new drive? I got a new laptop and just put the drive from the old one in the new one and that was it.

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [How to copy an Ubuntu install from one laptop to another](https://askubuntu.com/q/62340/301745)

Answer (score 30):

**Prerequisites:**

The same version of Ubuntu is installed on both machines. The architecture (32/64 bit) can be different.

**Step 1: Store the list of installed packages**

Run the following command on the source machine to store the installed packages names in ~/pkglist:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | sed "s/.*deinstall//" | sed "s/install$//g" > ~/pkglist
```

**Step 2: Transfer your config**

Use scp or rsync or even a flash drive to transfer your home directory (~/*, ~/.*), the source list (/etc/apt/sources.list) and any other files you customized or installed (like apache config under /etc or softwares on /opt) from the source machine to the target one.

**Step 3: Install packages**

On the target machine run the following command in a failsafe terminal session to install your packages:

```
sudo aptitude update && cat pkglist | xargs sudo aptitude install -y
```

Extract from:

http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/

Comment: Step 2 is still rather vague

Comment: There may be a change to Ubuntu's setup because following these instructions will cause system failure - necessitating a re-installation of the operating system. Best option is to just start from scratch on the new machine.

Comment: @mjp True. This rendered my freshly installed ubuntu 16.04 unusable. After running the install package commands System Settings went missing. I restarted. The machine then rebooted into a blank desktop. I tried to reinstall unity desktop from command but no result. Going to re-install ubuntu

Comment: To find changes in /etc I used  `debsums -ce`

Comment: This does not work anymore!
See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006641/upon-fresh-installing-a-list-of-packages-dselect-upgrade-returns-an-empty-list

Comment: Do NOT just simply copy-paste! E.g. if you switch from AMD to Intel or vice versa there might be specific packages for each chipset

Answer (score 11):

First off, [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/17823/6161) this question covers exporting (then installing) your exact set of packages.

As you noted, most of your configuration will be in /home.

That being said, each time I do this, I start from scratch so to speak.  I'll install ubuntu and manually add packages that I know I use, configuring them one at a time.  The list of packages installed on your old computer is a good starting place to find different pieces.  Once stuff is more or less set up, I'll then copy over just the data files (but not the config files) from my old computer.  This does take more time to do, but it's worth it to switch to the newest version.  (My old desktop runs 10.04, my new on currently runs 11.10, although I plan on updating that to 12.04 when it has been around for a month to work off any remaining rough edges)   But this plan is for if you're ok with a few things working slightly differently than before.  If you *need* things to be exactly the same, go ahead and do the above.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for an easier way of doing this and I found [Aptik](https://teejeetech.com/product/aptik/):

> Aptik is a tool for migrating settings and data from one Linux
> installation to another. It can be used while re-installing the
> operating system, and when moving to next release of a Linux
> distribution.

I just used it to migrate from an old laptop to a new one, both running Ubuntu 18.04. Seemed to work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for this! While it's not free ($25 for a personal license), it is much more comprehensive than most other answers here (getting custom repos, packages, configurations, and more in addition to just the home directory) and apparently doesn't bork an Ubuntu 18.04 install, which appears to be the result of some of the other, older answers here when applied to modern distros.

Answer (score 0):

There are several utilities that can make direct copies of your file system and some (Norton Ghost for example) can adjust your partitions to adapt to the new disk.  Software like this allows you to not only copy from disk to disk but also keep a separate, compressed backup for yourself in the future.

There's also the tool `dd` to do this, however it takes a bit more knowledge and research to produce the results that you would like.

Comment: There's also filezilla which works well.

Comment: @ShadowMitia Clonezilla I guess you meant?

Comment: Norton Ghost? No thanks we have rsync and gParted...

Answer (score 0):

Most configs and personal files will be in `/home`. For example by default my GNOME theme, shell settings, Chromium history/bookmarks/etc., vimrc, bash_profile, and most settings carried over nicely.

An important thing is to preserve permissions and timestamps. See [Copy files without losing file/folder permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225865/copy-files-without-losing-file-folder-permissions) The `-a` flag for rsync is ideal for this. Rsync is recommended for large file transfers. [Use `--partial-dir` to be able to restart progress](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252969/171025). I also exclude `.gvfs` (not a real file) and [`.cache`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102046/is-it-okay-to-delete-the-cache-folder).

---

Also consider installing /home on a separate partition if you are just reinstalling the system on the same hard drive. [What are the pros and cons of having a separate home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition)

Answer (score -1):

Remember that you can easily remove your hard disk from one machine to another without any problem.

Comment: Not necessarily, if the new system is a laptop and 1) the drive has a 3.5" form factor or 2) even with the right form factor all drive bays of the laptop are full.