# Are the advantages of having /home on a separate partition actually advantages?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

With reference to answers given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition), it is mentioned multiple times that the main advantage is the ability to change/reinstall Ubuntu versions without losing configuration files. However, will a new install not require all you applications to be reinstalled ?

Living in countries where internet connections are slow, won't reinstalling the applications, updating OS, installing drivers just negate this advantage ? You might spend less time switching between Ubuntu versions' but you will spend as much time or more, making them usable each time.

Comment: The new Ubuntu installer since 12.10 provides a new *upgrade* feature direct from USB/CD, but *not* when you have separated home – this is another disadvantage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your home partition are all your settings files and personal files stored. The hidden settings files can be shown in Nautilus by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. So when reinstalling Ubuntu, with a separate home partition, you will keep your Firefox settings, text editor settings, ssh keys, photos, documents, etc. But yes, you will need to reinstall the actual programs.

Another advantage may be that you have a small SSD (60 GB perhaps) for the OS, and then you can have your home partition on a separate, larger mechanical HDD, where the speed isn't as essential and space is more needed.