# Running Ubuntu on a hybrid laptop

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, 19.04, hybrid

I am purchasing a hybrid laptop which has a 256GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. This is the first time i'm purchasing a laptop with a SSD and hybrid storage. I intend to install Ubuntu on my SSD and store files (/home) on my HDD. I have no prior expereince with installing an OS on such specs. How should i proceed with installation and is there any problems which i may run into, or any tips?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048854/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-ssdhdd-hybrid-with-proper-partitioning) may be of help to you.  I would recommend keeping your /home folder on the SSD also and use the HDD for extra storage, The reason I say that is a lot of programs use the /home folder for hidden config files and if they have to get it from the HDD you'll notice a slowdown in those programs. But the choice is yours.

Comment: I usually store a lot of big sized mp4 videos and a huge music library. If that remains in the home folder, wouldn't it get too big for the SSD?

Comment: you can use the Hdd and Partition it as a /Data partition or call it movies or anything you want and move them mp4 files to the Hdd.  you do not have to leave them in the home partition.