# Can't write to mounted ext4 hard drive in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

I just built a new computer. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm *not* dual-booting.

Ubuntu is installed on my SSD, but I'd like to also use an internal HDD (connected via SATA to my motherboard) for additional storage. I've been following [this set of instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048871/947989) to set things up. The HDD is formatted as ext4 and automatically mounts at boot, but that's as far as I've got. I'm stuck on Step 4, moving folders from ~/home/ to the HDD and making symbolic links.

I can't drag folders from Home to the mounted HDD via the file explorer. I also cannot create new directories in the mounted HDD via the file explorer. When I check the permissions of the mounted HDD (via right-click->Properties->Permissions), it says "The permissions of 'drivename' could not be determined."

From doing some further research, I suspect this is a permissions issue; however, I have been unable to determine what specifically I need to do. How do I troubleshoot this and write to my internal HDD?

**Edit:** The contents of my /etc/fstab file are as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=b928c257-beab-4352-81d0-9ae12955bf96 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=5B6B-1052  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=8d372b78-f15c-4c85-b853-becfafa28d69 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=1972e189-a0fe-448d-93db-c17028c913c8 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c0c74b6f-dedb-4a3e-b5d8-52cca8a0958e /mnt/stuff auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Stuff 0 0
```

**Edit 2:** Here's the relevant entry from running `lsblk -fm -e 7`:

```
sda  ext4         c0c74b6f-dedb-4a3e-b5d8-52cca8a0958e /mnt/stuff   1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
```

Comment: The HDD mount options could be the issue. Please edit your question and copy/paste the content of the `/etc/fstab` file

Comment: `lsblk -fm -e 7` may help too

Comment: Thanks, @cmak.fr. I've updated the question with the contents of the `fstab` file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The HDD mount made by the gnome-disk-manager should be ok
I guess you just have to fix perms on HDD :
Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command below

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/stuff
```

If this does not the trick, go next:

---

The last line of `/etc/fstab` should be your HDD
You may edit this last line
Main change is in the mount options (defaults) and fsck option (2)

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab #(or sudo gedit /etc/fstab)
#
# Edit the last line
UUID=c0c74b6f-dedb-4a3e-b5d8-52cca8a0958e /mnt/stuff ext4 defaults        0       2
```

Save the file and change (take) ownership on HDD

```
# Remount the HDD
sudo umount -f /mnt/stuff
sudo mount -a
sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/stuff
# non recursive change of ownership should be enough, but
# if still cannot write on it, go for a (longer) recursive change of ownership
# sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/stuff
# -R is for recursive
```

Comment: The `sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/stuff` command seems to have done it. Thank you. What did that specifically do?

Comment: it gives to your user the ownership on the drive

Comment: ... but this is crazy ... then only that user can write on the entire disk. This seems like a patch rather than a right answer.

Comment: @Rafael: I agree this is crazy. On another site, one person mentioned doing a chmod 777. But perhaps we need a better way to create file/folder permissions for external hard disks. For now I think I'll just format the partition back to NTFS.

Comment: Don't put it in `fstab` if it is removable and you expect the machine to boot with the drive disconnected. The kernel will freak out during boot if a partition in `fstab` won't mount.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create a universal USB drive that can be accessed by all OS.
I use FreeBSD (Unix) as my primary desktop.

So it is vital that I create ext4 file systems within my desktop (FreeBSD).
I have done so and now need to test if it can work on Linux (Arch Linux).

It happens to mount after manually entering the following commands:
`$ sudo mkdir /mnt/some_name_for_drive`
`$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdx /mnt/some_name_for_drive`

But then I had write issues, so I did the following as mentioned by the user "cmak.fr":

`sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/some_name_for_drive`

I am now able to write to the USB drive in which I created an ext4 external drive from FreeBSD.