# problem with adding my internal hdd

Tags: hard-drive, 20.04, hybrid

I'm new to ubuntu, and have a hybrid hard disk (2 TB HDD , 256 SSD)

I have done the things in this:
[How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)
and mounted it in /hdd

I think I have done something wrong, or I don't know what I'm doing :(

I can't access the hard disk from the 'files'
and If i enter the directory of that i can't edit it, just read-only...
Just when i click on the /hdd in the gnome-disks , then i could edit it

also in  [How to install Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD+HDD hybrid with proper partitioning?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048854)
I cant do the fourth step...

I'm a bit confused, I just want to use my HDD as where i save my files, and it would be great if i can link the folders in home to there.

anyone can tell me what should I do or what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next to correctly mounting your drive, you also need to set the desired ownership and permissions. Drives that are automatically mounted during startup (i.e., included in the configuration file `/etc/fstab`) are by default owned by the administrator ("`root`"). Depending on default permissions of the system, other users will have read access only, or may have no access at all.

It is normal (and actually desired) that you do not see the drive 'as such' in Files. In linux, you can link any storage from within the home folder. Thus, from the user's perspective, all storage is neatly in his home. It is only the administrator that needs to be aware that, in reality, the storage is under `/hdd` (in your case).

**Changing ownership**

You can change the ownership of the mount point (`/hdd`) to give the entire mounted partition to a user. You can also assign subfolders of `/hdd`, that means folders on the mounted drive, to a user or to different users.

To change the ownership of the mount point, use a command like:

```
sudo chown <user>:<group> /hdd
```

Substitute the login name of the user and the group that needs to be owner. On Ubuntu, each user also belongs to a group of the same name, so  may then be the same login.

**Changing permissions**

After changing the ownership, there will be no need to change permissions. Each folder has permissions ("read", "write" and "execute"). By default, owner and group have all permissions, "others" can read and execute, but not write.

**Linking your folders**

Indeed, you can move the data folder to the hard drive, and replace them with a symbolic link that points to the new location. From a user perspective and for practical purposes, such a link acts and feels like a real folder.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, i have a few things to ask, a ".cache" , ".config" , ".local" and a ".bash_history" are getting made in my home directory, what are those ?  and is it ok to link the snap folder to the hdd too?  and the last thing, in my hdd, a lost+found and a ".trash-0" are mader with a lock and a x are on them, they're broke but i cant delete them because of premission, what should i do with them?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Feel free to ask questions about Ubuntu. Each question should only be a single question. Obviously, first search whether a similar question has not yet been asked. Do NOT link the snap folder: that will not work. Only link your own data folders (Documents, Movies, etc.). Also user configuration data (the hidden . dot files) can be linked, but there is probably no need to. Best leave all these hidden config files alone as an unexperienced user.

Comment: **thanks** and yup I'll should've post those seperately