# Could not play media files on external drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, root, udisks, hybrid

I am new to Ubuntu and recently made a switch from Windows to it.

I have a hybrid system for which I installed Ubuntu 20.04 with the help of [How to install Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD+HDD hybrid with proper partitioning?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048854/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-ssdhdd-hybrid-with-proper-partitioning). I have the exact same specification and did follow every step except the *swap*. Now, my 1TB HDD is mounted as 700GB to `mnt/Media`, 200GB to `/media/user/Work` and the remaining 100GB is `EFI System`.

Now, except for photos and .pdf files I couldn't open any file. For videos specifically, VLC show the following error:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'admin:///mnt/Media/Movies/Green.Book.2018.DVDSCR.MkvCage.ws.mkv'. Check the log for details.
```

Same file when kept in home directory plays properly. Also, when I try to play the media files with root access via `sudo nautilus`, it shows `There is no application installed for "MPEG-4 video" files`.

Can somebody explain to me what to do here? I want to access my external HDD like I used to do it in Windows.

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I got it done. I changed the respective drive Partition Type to 'Basic Data' and change the partition type to 'NTFS'.