# If you plan on using already created file systems, be aware... Upon Re-installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 18.04, reinstall

​
Hi, I'm new here

```
If I've made any mistake with this question please let me know and pardon me with time to edit it. Thanks.
```

**My Destination:**

I'm trying to **re-install my Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit** in my dell Inspiron 13 5000series i7.
I currently have two operating systems Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04 as ***dual-boot***.

I've already backed up everything, but if I can reinstall ***without losing my entire disk and my win10 and it's files*** - I would be very thankful.

**My Approach So Far:**

These are the steps I took before I got here. Using a live installation:

*The reinstall by erasing* - I've read it might delete the whole system - **I've not** taken this road.

[So I chose "Something else"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA1yn.png) -- In the picture my partitioning.

[Here is the only thing I've changed - the mounting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zfik.png)

> *[And lastly the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Lzd.png) -- **This is why I'm posting this question***

**Why I'm worried:**
Someone has raised a question about this but was not given an actual answer:
https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-desktop/issues/278

This is the bug I'm worried about:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/556373

From what I've understood it might remove the whole disk, not only
my linux system and files but also my win10..

Because I've half read half guessed it might stems from the home and root being connected
I've checked mine using the `df -h` and guess what:
[They are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ4fz.png)

**Before going on**:

```
 Is it really the source of the problem? or
is there something else I should do? maybe going on won't case any harm to my win10?
```

---

---

So now I'm trying to separate between them - I don't know where I'm going with this.

I'v been following this tutorial to separate my home from my root:
https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/

This is where I got stuck because upon creating the NEW partition to
be the /home the label (or path) is ambiguous "New Partition #1" and I can't find how to put it in a path:
[Unclear Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mud09.png)

I'm afraid to do the changes because if the path is ambiguous how could I carry on with reaching this home
partition which is nowhere to be found path-wise.

**In summery:**

> 1). If you plan on using already created file systems, be aware...

**How do we deal with this kind of warning upon reinstalling - without losing data, or at least not losing any other operating system (like win10).**

2). If actually by separating home from root (which is only a guess on my part) how to create a path (or label) in the `gparted` new partition?

*Thanks in advanced.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you need not to ***separate*** `/home` and `/` partitions if you don't really need. Rest is all your wish. You can read [Ish's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142704).

The warning states that:

> No partition table changes and no creation of filesystems have been planned.
>   If you plan on using already created file systems, be aware that existing files may prevent the successful installation of the base system.

Actually, Linux(let's say Ubuntu here) works on *extended* file system which is quite obvious that it is a standard. You previously had Ubuntu installed in that partition(lets say `sdax`). Since you already have that partition with `ext4` filesystem and you are just continuing without any changes or creation of **File System**. It expects that you might have partition in another file system and expects you to change or create a new file system.

Like I already said that Ubuntu works on `ext` file system and it *might* expect you to change filesystem or at least format your partition(you haven't checked on `Format this partition` box). That's why *be aware that existing files may prevent the successful installation of the base system*.

So, just choose `Format this partition` and install Ubuntu as usual.

Comment: Thank you for the soothing words.
And about the main question: "Format this partition" is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The warning simply means** that you won't be *erasing* all files on the existing filesystem, but instead *overwriting* a selection of them. If you have a truly haywired or strangely-customized system, this may cause problems since the installer is not omniscient and will not try to understand your changes.

In ordinary usage, you are unlikely to encounter problems. I've used this install method many times without problem...but I tend to overwrite an uncustomized, stock Ubuntu with another stock Ubuntu.

Since you have backups, it's safe to select the option to Format the partition, which will delete everything and start you fresh.

**The bug** you are worried about was fixed eight years ago. Since you are not installing 10.04, it is very unlikely to affect you. If you are worried about some similar kind of behavior, that's reasonable. Address that worry by having backups, recording your Win 10 Product Key on paper, and knowing where to get Win 10 reinstall media from the MS website.

**It is unwise** for new users (like you) to follow random advice you find on unofficial websites and blogs (like howtogeek). They are full of opinion, rumor, shockingly bad advice, and obsolete ideas. There is nothing wrong with keeping `/` and `/home` on the same partition. That was a common practice 10-15 years ago for a lot of good reasons, few of which apply today - disks are bigger and OS are more reliable. There is also nothing wrong with keeping them on separate partitions. As a new user, feel free to try both (it's allowed)...and regardless of which you choose as your personal preference, keep good backups.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid opening an actual post so I've looked around as much as I could. I should not be abashed asking here :)

Answer (score 0):

The bug you mention was fixed about eight years ago (see toward the bottom of your link).

A reinstall requires erasing things on your hard drive, yes, but only your old Ubuntu installation. It doesn't require erasing Windows.

Before doing anything, **back up anything you want to save from Ubuntu**, maybe in Dropbox or something like that or a USB drive. You might also consider doing the same with important files in Windows.

Also, when working below, do **NOT** do anything to `ntfs` partitions.

## Getting a separate `/home` partition

A separate `/home` partition is usually not recommended because it wastes space (when one partition is full, it can't use the space in the other), so you should do it only if you have a good reason to.

If you want a separate `/home` partition, delete the `ext4` partition by selecting it with your mouse and pressing the `-` button in the lower left. Then, click on the new free space, click the `+` button, and create a `/` partition that takes up only part of the free space. Then, click the remaining free space, press the `+` button, and create a `/home` partition with the remaining space. Format both of them if it gives the option to.

## Formatting the `/` partition

If you skipped making a `/home` partition, do the same thing you did before, except check next to `Format the partition` in the picture below and set the mount point to `/` again:

[image: screenshot]

This will completely erase `/dev/sda5` that contains your old Ubuntu installation. So backup any files you need from your old Ubuntu installation onto your Windows partition or something like Dropbox or a USB drive, because they'll be erased and you probably won't be able to get them back.

However, it will erase *only* that partition (as it says, `Format the partition`), *leaving alone* other partitions like `/dev/sda3` that contains Windows. That will make the base system installation work nicely while not messing with Windows.

Comment: Thanks you. This is very encouraging because I suspected I'm treading on troubled waters with the separation as a source for the warning which IS A MISTAKE and the answer is to tick the FORMAT THE PARTITION as you've said.