# EEE-PC 1000HE install questions

Tags: asus, eeepc

## UPDATE

BIOS allows for booting from SD card slot, a program like Unetbootin can be used to configure a bootable SD card Ubuntu installer.  lubuntu 16.04 failed to install, whereas 15.10 was successful.  Decided on Xubuntu 16.04

## ORIGINAL POST

If you have had success installing Ubuntu on the 1000HE: please state this in the first sentence of your response.

I was unable to boot from USB so I have a few questions. I tinkered with the BIOS settings (per youTube and other websites) and only the SATA HDD would show up as a bootable device option.  ESC lists boot options.

Questions:

1) Is it possible to boot from USB?  Maybe I missed a step.  Bonus if you successfully performed this and reply with the specifics of the procedure.

2) What sacrifices / shortcoming should be expected with Ubuntu that are specific to the 1000HE?

3) Is there a technique to configure a SATA drive with another PC to install Ubuntu?  The drive would be configured as bootable and the 1000HE would boot the drive and Ubuntu would configure itself. Maybe a transplant from another donor Ubuntu PC?

I found this [link regarding Ubuntu and the 1000HE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Asus_Eee_1000HE)  but the issues was with Ubuntu 9.04 in 2009.  I look-forward to a post indicating success and pitfalls to avoid.  Thanks

Comment: It was sugggested in another thread that a16-bit FAT filesystem for the bootable USB flashdrive might be recognized when the ESC key is pressed.   Tests with a 16-bit FAT boot was unsucessful.    Wondering if updating the BIOS is the key to USB bootability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Ubuntu on an EEE 1015PX with no major hurdles.

1. Where the USB drive won't show in boot device selection:

   - Confirm the drive is bootable on another computer
   - Read the computer's manual, or look through the BIOS settings, for any info about "boot from USB"
2. Nothing specific, just don't expect the thing to be fast, since it's a 7-year old netbook. For that reason, you'll probably want to install a lighter flavour like Lubuntu.
3. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/598312/301745) says you can install Ubuntu on another computer, and just swap the drive - nothing too complicated. Just make sure you install the right architecture for the receiving computer. I suggest 32bit because the machine is older and only has 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Good suggestions.  Especially with questions 2&3.  With regard to question 1: a known-good bootable Sandisk USB drive was used.  Attempts to find \ Google EEE 1000HE and bootable USB did not bear any fruit. Attempt to configure Sandisk USB did not work.