# Upon fresh installing a list of packages dselect-upgrade returns an empty list

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

This is the third time I used this exact same method to install all my packages on a fresh install of Ubuntu. The 2 previous were successful . But this time `dselect-upgrade` returns an empty list, nothing to install ...

Prior to this I did re-install all the PPAs.

I got the list of packages to install on the new computer from a bash script on the prior working computer:

```
# apt install packages
dpkg --get-selections | grep install > $distrib_release_name.Package.List.install.$machine'.log'
```

The output is correct with the package name on each line with the `install` keyword to its right, here is an excerpt:

```
aaphoto                     install
```

I created a tmp folder in my new home directory and moved the package list there.

To re-install in Xenial 16.04 (from Xenial 16.04) I did enter the following cmd. lines on the new machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dselect
$ sudo dselect update
$ cd /home/ubuntu-xenial/user/tmp
$ sudo dpkg --set-selections < Xenial.16.04.Package.List.install.Julius-PC.log
```

A long list of warnings ensues. But unlike the other times I find all the packages in the warning list, minus those already present on the new install. Those lines looks like:

```
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 2: aaphoto
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 2: abiword
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 2: abiword-common
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 2: abiword-plugin-grammar
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 2: account-plugin-aim
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 4: account-plugin-foursquare
[...]
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1825: zint-qt-devel
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1827: zlib1g:i386
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1827: zlib1g-dev:amd64
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1827: zsh
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1827: zsh-common
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method
$
```

Also the line numbering suggest that the cmd. to install packages is build 'behind', as several package names are on the same line as expected. But the error prevent any action ...

I got these warnings in a file named `dpkg--set-selections-warnings.log`
I believe this is a reference to the `apt database` on the current new install ?

Then to get the package list to be installed in a text file:

```
$ echo n | sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade > dselect-upgrade.packages.list.to.be.installed.log
```

Then to perform the upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

That was working fine the last 2 times, however right now the content of the file `dselect-upgrade.packages.list.to.be.installed.log` is quite empty as well (as expected matching the cmd. line output above):

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

I am lost at finding why the packages to be installed is an empty list.

`[NOTE]:` Almost 1 month after posting, still no answer. I would have expected something from the 'official' Ubuntu team as it definitely looks like some system packages configuration / behaviour did change over time. I don't see any other explanation as this command applies to a 'fresh install' of Ubuntu LTS... Of course there are some bypass solutions which are not elegant at all... Like forcing the install of all packages through `apt`, but all didn't fit in only one command, I had to limit the nbr. of package per cmd. to between 500 / 1000. As well in the end some packages are dependencies and were already installed before. Why this great `UNIX` feature is completely broken in `Ubuntu` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Well, after researching on `Debian` bugs, I found this [page](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=703092#75) about this person complaining about the new behaviour of `dselect-upgrade` which is seen as 'orthodox` by maintainers. Still it looks like the manpage let the users we are, completely blindfolded by the change. Warm welcome to free software :)

So the solution is pretty clear now. You need to install the `dctrl-tools` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dctrl-tools
```

Then you need to sync the database, as otherwise the new behaviour of `dselect-upgrade` will only let it aware of the current set of packages in the `apt database`.

```
$ sudo sync-available
Merging available database in /tmp/apt-available.80qLJ6...done.
Replacing available packages info, using /tmp/apt-available.80qLJ6.
Information about 88311 packages was updated.
$
```

Then proceed as usual:

```
$ sudo dpkg --set-selections < Xenial.16.04.Installed.Packages.GA-Z370-AORUS-G7.log
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 29: adobereader-enu:i386
[...]
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 7929: zint-qt
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 7929: zint-qt-devel
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method
$
```

This time it's fully working as I have only 32 packages not found in the database, as they are build either locally or directly available from different vendors.

```
$ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aaphoto abiword abiword-common abiword-plugin-grammar account-plugin-aim account-plugin-foursquare
  account-plugin-identica account-plugin-instagram account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-twitter
  account-plugin-yahoo acetoneiso acpica-tools acpidump activity-log-manager-control-center adequate advancecomp
[...]
  xsel xserver-xephyr xsltproc xtightvncviewer xtrans-dev xubuntu-icon-theme xutils-dev xvfb xvid4conf xzdec xzgv
  y-ppa-manager yad yasm yelp-tools youtube-dl zeitgeist zim zlib1g:i386 zlib1g-dev zsh zsh-common
0 upgraded, 6074 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,138 MB/7,140 MB of archives.
After this operation, 24.2 GB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
$
```

For the purpose of documenting this Ask Ubuntu question I answered no. Later I will use the process described in my question above to keep a file trace of the upgrade. But this time around it's working as expected at last!