# Can i just remove the ~/.cache directory?

Tags: 14.04

My 128GB SSD is almost full. I just checked the disk analyzer and found the ~/.cache is consuming a great deal of disk space, and I have no idea what the ~/.cache directory is used for. Can I just remove it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it okay to delete ~/.cache?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/102046/is-it-okay-to-delete-cache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer:  Yes, but it will fill up again over time, and may cause some minor, but self-fixing issues.