# I have got garbage in home catalog

Tags: 14.04

I want to clean my home directory from garbage, but I've got in trouble after I saw some weird files. What should not be touched, can you make list of these files?

Comment: I assume you are talking about configuration files of applications. In that case don't consider them junk. Don't delete anything unless sure. Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102046/is-it-okay-to-delete-cache

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a list. You need to find the files you think are unnecessary, and find out more (eg. using google) to see where do they come from, and if they are safe to be deleted.

Each file you have there has been created with a purpose. So only you as the user can decide whether you still need them or not.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is a very difficult question to answer right away.

If you open a file browser on that directory you will see the main directories of the user (such as Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Music, etc.) but there will be (maybe) some other directories and files which are created by the programs you used.
If you enable the file browser to show you the hidden files/directories you'll see a lot more.

Now, some of them were created by the programs you use on your machine and they still may be used.
Others may be of programs you used to have but were uninstalled.
These last ones may be deleted but you'll have to know which can and cannot be deleted.

That's why it can't be a strait answer: because it depends on the files/directories YOU have and the programs YOU use.
If you showed us a list... then you could have some more help.