# How to auto clear cache on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, cache

The .cache folder(The folder with cache) is eating up my space most of the time and I always how to clear it. How do I get Ubuntu to automatically delete every cache file, including clearing the recycle bin whenever it deletes it but only files that were in the cache folder not the ones deleted by me?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: The .cache folder can contain data including browser history and preferences. Please see [Is it okay to delete ~/.cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102046/is-it-okay-to-delete-cache) for more information.**

If you would still like to continue, the best way is to have a cron job that regularly empties the recycle bin and deletes `.cache`. Your computer may act weirdly until a reboot, so it is probably best to do this at boot time.

Create a script named `clearcache.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`. You may need root permissions. Replace yourusername with your username. Edit it with your favourite text editor and add the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /home/yourusername/.cache /home/yourusername/.local/share/Trash
mkdir /home/yourusername/.cache /home/yourusername/.local/share/Trash
```

Run `crontab -e` and add the following line at the end of the file to run every 30 minutes:

```
*/30 * * * * /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/clearcache.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or this line for every boot:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/clearcache.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or you can use a different time in the `crontab` just as long as the command is `/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/clearcache.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the command sudo rm -rf scares me. I'll think about using it in the future.

Comment: I don't see where the question you linked corroborates the warning that you gave.

Comment: @agamer569 It isn't  **`sudo`** `rm -rf` (its `rm -rf`), but having a healthy fear of it is a good thing.  But the reason I don't use `sudo` is because it is unnessecary. Don't use `sudo` when not needed.