# File system has run out of space, it says 0 space. How can I put it right?

Tags: filesystem

File system has run out of space, it says 0 space. How can I put it right? I can't watch my tutorial videos as they keep crashing, and same with Youtube. I'm not very savvy when it comes to a computer and haven't a clue what to do to put this right!

Comment: Please add the following results to your question (from the terminal): `df -h` and `lsblk`.

Comment: You didn't tell us what OS/release you are using, but Ubuntu recommends a minimum size of 25gb disk space being allocated (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) so possibly you allocated less than that (many users do, but they need to be careful with what they do with their system when they have less space) or you've added more software/files than your allocated space allows for (myself I treat 32gb as the minimum for what I use my system for).  In my case I'd look where you saw the 0 & remove unnecessary files, or allocate more space but you weren't very specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score 2):

Type "sudo apt clean" into a terminal. It will ask for your password so type that in when prompted.This will clean out a cache and may get you working again but you probably need to see where all your space has gone as per the comment by @ajgringo619. If you need help understanding the output of those commands just post again. Uninstalling any programs you don't need will also help.

Answer (score 0):

From [5 Simple Ways To Free Up Space on Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/5-ways-free-up-space-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

These are the two easiest steps, read the article for the other three steps.

---

Use this command to see the size of your cache

```
du -sh ~/.cache
```

Mine is only 1.3 GB but others are reported at 13 GB here:

- [Is it okay to delete the ~/.cache folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102046/is-it-okay-to-delete-the-cache-folder)

Be **careful** following the advise in this Q&A.