# How can I see the memory occupied by a file and folder and also entire directory from terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, memory-usage

I'm having some files and folders in the "My Documents" directory. What are the commands to see the size of a file and directory in a terminal?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will summarise the sizes of the directories:

```
du -h
```

PS: Although all computer storage is technically "memory", this term is usually reserved for non-persistent storage like RAM and CPU cache.

Comment: good one for quick recursive results.. +1

Answer (score 8):

To see the full size (including whole content) of a folder in a directory, use the command

```
du -hs YOUR_FOLDER_NAME
```

To see the full size (including whole content) of **all** folders and files in a directory, use the command

```
ls | xargs -I fileorfolder du -hs fileorfolder
```

Answer (score 5):

Try these commands,

```
cd ~/Documents
ls -shR
```

Comment: `ls -sh` for size and better readability.. and switch `-R` if recursive output is needed.. +1

Comment: Not completely satisfied. The size of a folder is given, but not of the **total size of the content** in the folder.   See also this [answer about the total size of a folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224/how-do-i-determine-the-total-size-of-a-directory-folder-from-the-command-line)