# How can I print the breakdown of disk usage by directory?

Tags: filesystem, disk, disk-usage

My cloud instance (running a web app) disk usage went up inexplicably, I suspect there is something like a storage leak there. Is there any way to  the breakdown of disk usage by directory, in order to find out the directories that take up a lot of storage, so that I can investigate?

Note that in this cloud instance, I don't have GUI and have to rely on the terminal (through SSH).

The difference between this question and [the linked related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224/how-do-i-determine-the-total-size-of-a-directory-folder-from-the-command-line) is I want to find a breakdown, not just total usage of a directory.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [How do I determine the total size of a directory (folder) from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1224/how-do-i-determine-the-total-size-of-a-directory-folder-from-the-command-line?)

Comment: On a second thought, do you have X installed on the cloud instance at all?

Comment: @kos What is X?

Comment: I meant Xorg (package `xorg`). Is it listed if you run `dpkg -l | grep 'xorg'` on your cloud instance? I know you said you have no GUI installed, so technically that rules out even a window manager such as Xorg, but GUI is a pretty broad term, at first I assumed you referred to a desktop manager, but maybe you don't even have a window manager installed.

Answer (score 4):

You could try *gt5*. It lists the disk usage of the contents your current directory, or a specified directory,  ordered by highest to lowest. If you see that, for example, /var/tmp is using a lot of space, you can do:

```
sudo gt5 /var/tmp
```

To see the usage of that folders contents. To see the basics of where in your system the disk use is going, try:

```
sudo gt5 /
```

To get it, simply do:

```
sudo apt-get install gt5
```

Comment: I'm on mobile, it kept forcing the capitals on me. Do not capitalize sudo.

Answer (score 3):

Disk Usage Analyzer (AKA `baobab`) is great to get a quick breakdown of where the disk space is going; so I'd suggest using Disk Usage Analyzer through SSH with X forwarding.

X forwarding should be enabled both on the client and on the server in order to work; it should be enabled by default on the server, so it should be just a matter of enabling it in the current client session:

```
ssh -X user@host baobab
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `du -sh *` in the root directory.

Comment: Please add a few more words to explain what you're suggesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Other utility available in many distros (and Windows' Cygwin) for disk usage analysis in console mode is `ncdu`, where

```
ncdu -q /home/user
```

will show a browseable list of directories/files conveniently sorted by size. The option `-q` increases the refresh interval of progress reporting, speeding the gathering of directory data.

Pressing <kbd>h</kbd> shows the hotkeys list, and <kbd>q</kbd> closes the program.

Other very useful option when searching for space hogs is `-x` for checking only the partition where is the target directory, ignoring links that refer to other partitions:

```
ncdu -xq /
```

As always, `man ncdu` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `du` command to print the breakdown of disk usage by directory. The `du` command can recursively calculate the size of directories and their contents, and the `sort` command can be used to sort the results by size.

Here's an example command that will print the breakdown of disk usage by directory, sorted by size:

```
du -h / | sort -h
```

This command will calculate the disk usage of the root directory (`/`) and all its subdirectories, and display the sizes in a human-readable format (`-h`). The `sort -h` command will sort the output by size, with the smallest directories first and the largest directories last.

You can modify the command to start from a different directory if you suspect that the storage leak is coming from a specific directory. For example, if you suspect that the leak is coming from the `/var` directory, you can use the following command:

```
du -h /var | sort -h
```

This will calculate the disk usage of the `/var` directory and its subdirectories, and display the sizes sorted by size.

Once you have identified the directories that are taking up a lot of storage, you can investigate further to determine the cause of the storage leak.